# К удалить последний слеш в URL

Tags: .htaccess, apache, url

К удалить последний слеш в URL с помощью .htaccess для такого кода

`https://page/about/`<-**Этот слеш**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .+/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]


DirectorySlash Off
```

Добавьте в .htaccess

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но не помогло

Comment: @Rivera Time Club, Дополнил ответ. Попробуйте